# Problems with creating a list in PHP

Tags: php, list, echo, hybrid-mobile-app

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my list? It's my first time creating a list in PHP and an error came up when running it. The error said:

"**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'col' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Pinder/CMS/event.php on line 410**"

I want to be able to have 2 containers with a gap between them. which is why I've went for the col-md 6,2,6.

**Here is my code**:

```
// List
      echo_lines(array(
        "<ul>", 
        "<div="col-md-6">""</div>",
        "<div="col-md-2">""</div>",
        "<div="col-md-6">""</div>",
        "</ul>",
      ));
```

Comment: did u got solution ?? or i would write it for you

Comment: Yeah it was a stupid mistake... I'll mark the response correct when the timer has finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes in your code like so (also note the dots `.` which concatenate the string):

```
// List
      echo_lines(array(
        "<ul>", 
        "<div class=\"col-md-6\">" . "</div>",
        "<div class=\"col-md-2\">" . "</div>",
        "<div class=\"col-md-6\">" . "</div>",
        "</ul>",
      ));
```

As you can see, I have also added `class` in front of the equal-sign... I think you missed that one as well...

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't think so, since `col-md-6` is used twice... And id's can only be used once on a page..